# Requesting payment for a tax code

Tags: taxes, scams

I have a UK savings account with Investec Bank in the UK which is currently holding 2 Millions.  I want to transfer that money to my US savings account but the bank said I needed to pay/send them 10,000 first so that I can receive a TAX CODE immediately so that the funds can be released. What is this Tax Code for and what does the country use it for.

The bank told me the following:

> In united kingdom Government constitution of 1954, section 4.11. It
>   say Tax is a composary levy impose by the government to the citizen
>   and Tax payee is also used for the development of the country. Your
>   transfer was stop by the United Kingdom Tax Board Authorities because
>   you have not paid your Tax Fee.

Please advise if this is true since I live in the States and don't know UK laws/regulations.

Comment: That is a scam.   Do you really believe you have 2 Million that you don't know how to get clear access to?  Where did this money come from? A rich uncle? A Nigerian Prince?

Comment: You don't need to know many UK laws/regulations.  A quick google search will give a strong indication there is no "constitution of 1954" of the United Kingdom.  Quoting a non-existent document is a bit of a red flag.

Comment: You can tell the quote is fake as soon as the second word.

Comment: The 3rd, 11th, 15th and 21st words are also a bit of a giveaway that the quote doesn't come from a British bank.

Answer (score 15):

This is an [advanced fee scam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam): you do not have any money in a foreign account, nor will paying any taxes or fees get that money.

A clue is that the [Constitution of the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_United_Kingdom) has no mention of taxes and is also not organized into sections in a manner like "4.11".

If you really want to confirm this, you should be able to contact the [UK branch of Investec Bank](https://www.investec.com/en_gb.html). They would be able to confirm the means that they would use to contact individuals with account issues.